# Arrays.hashcode(int[]) gives same hash for different elements

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate a hash based on the integers in an array. I am expecting arrays with different integers to not have the same hashcode:

given [72, 99] and doing Arrays.hashcode([72,99]) I get 3292

given [73, 68] and doing Arrays.hashcode([73, 68]) I also get 3292

Does someone know why this is occuring and have an alternative to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Java hash codes are primitive and coarse. What *are* you trying to achieve?

Comment: "I am expecting arrays with different integers to not have the same hashcode" -- wrong expectation. Since the hash code itself is an `int`, you cannot expect to have unique hash codes for all combinations of two or more `int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are simply not enough possible hashcode values to produce unique hash codes for integer arrays.

The hashcode value is an `int` which can have at most 2^32 distinct values.

An `int[1]` contains a single `int` which can have 2^32 distinct values. For such an array you can create a hash function that produces unique hash values for all values of the `int` it contains (and `Arrays.hashCode()` computes such a value).

An `int[2]` contains 2 `int`s which together can have 2^64 distinct values. That means that you cannot create a hash function that produces unique hash values - you necessarily have many collisions.

This is why data structures like `HashMap` cannot rely on the hashcode alone - they necessarily must also use the `equals()` method.

Whatever you use the value from `Arrays.hashCode()` for it is not sufficient. You must use `Arrays.equals()` too to distinguish arrays having the same hashcode.

---

Depending on your specific usecase it might be possible to manually create a hashing function that produces unique values for pairs of `int` values.

For example, if the input values (`a` and `b`) are restricted to the range from 0 to 999, you could create a hash function that calculates `1000*a + b`, which would be a unique value for all restricted input values.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your why question:

The [Arrays.hashCode(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-int:A-) call you're using has the same behavior as calling List.hashCode().

From [List.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--):

The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:

```
int hashCode = 1;
     for (E e : list)
         hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

and from [Integer.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode--), it looks like the value returned is literally equal to the int primitive of the Integer.

So it seems like the first numbers in each array being 1 apart, and the second number being exactly 31 apart, is why they return the same number.

Now as to what to do about this, like Zahid Khan said above, there is no guarantee that 2 different objects produce different hashCodes, even if those objects are not equal. There are potentially ways to work around this, but without knowing more about exactly what you want to achieve, it may be hard to suggest anything specific.

Comment: I am doing a dynamic programming exercise where I am trying to optimise by using memoization. So they idea was that I dont have to loop over the values in an array that is the same as a previous one by using the hash value of that array. (reading above that will not solve my problem).

Answer (score 3):

If two objects have the same hashcode then they are NOT necessarily equal. But the opposite is true: if the objects are equal, then they must have the same hashcode.

Reference: [hashCode contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Object.html)